# xcopy wont copy shortcuts

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Example code where shortcut resides:

```
    xcopy "Google Chrome.Ink" %CURRENTUSER%\Desktop
```

Another Example where chrome.exe exists:

```
    xcopy /B chrome.exe %CURRENTUSER%\Desktop
```

Both result in:

```
    0 File(s) copied
```

or Chrome.exe itself is copied even though the /B switch is given.

If **xcopy** can't copy shortcuts, are their any alternative methods while still using command line?

Comment: check this xcopy - http://www.petefreitag.com/item/99.cfm

Comment: Yes, those are the same results as if you were to do a xcopy /?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This may be a typo, but your "Google Chrome.Ink" extension is wrong (a shortcut has a .lnk extension, not a .ink one).

2) Your variable is wrong, the name of the variable that converts to the user directory is not CURRENTUSER, but USERPROFILE.

So what you want is

```
 xcopy "Google Chrome.lnk" %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
```

Comment: That's it. Bah, those pesky ID-10-T errors.